# wordpress custom modules/widget areas on the page? can i make my own?

Tags: hooks

im kind of a wordpress noob so please excuse my inexperience.

so long story short, ive been tasked with creating a WP theme (kinda simple) but, one of the areas, around footer area, has a few things they want, like a 2ndary menu/ bread crumbs etc...maybe even custom html box etc that i can do other things with later on, which i know WP provides via  plugins / widgets etc but, my question is

how can i make a custom area to "hook" these onto a specific area of a page?

for example, in joomla, i can mark any part of a page with **named** hooks and thereafter,
select whatever module i want to work with,  assign said widget to the area by name and thats it, style it there after.

Does wordpress have anything like this?i know theyre different platforms but is there anything like it or a wordpress equivalent to achieve this.

i see for example that most of the widgets etc, go into the wp_sidebar.
can i make my own area or are there other hooks that simulate what i described above?

Any tips/answers, links to read/research i gladly and humbly appreciate.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add additional widgetized sidebars to your theme by adding to your theme's functions.php.

If you have not already added widget support in the theme, include:

```
if (function_exists('register_sidebar'))
```

Then add:

```
// Footer Widgets
register_sidebar(array(
  'id' => 'footerwidgets',
  'name' => 'FooterWidgets',
  'description' => 'Widgets here are shown in the footer',
  'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
  'after_widget'  => '</div>',
  'before_title' => '<h2>',
  'after_title' => '</h2>'
));
```

Then in your theme add `<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'FoooterWidgets' ); ?>`

Now simply go into Appearance >> Widgets to add whatever you like to this area.

Wordpress Codex - [Widgetizing Themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes)

If you have not already added widget support, include

Comment: +1 For remembering the `%2$s` in the `before_widget`. I added the id also. **Theme developers:** Always let the Widget set the ID and class attributes!

Comment: Hello, thanks for your informative reply. ive done as you said and all worked as it should, it appeared in the widgets area BUT, i cant see anything. any widgets i add to the module if you will, doesnt show on the page. when i do a quick test on Firebug to search for it, it doesnt appear in the code either so its not coming through at all. Any ideas? thanks again

Comment: I just tested the code and it seems to be working as it is supposed to. Give me the URL and I will take a look at it.

Comment: ahh man its not online, im running it on WAMP/MAMP here at the house. What do you think it could be? when i Firebug the page (i added a text widget and added dummy words ) and i look for it on the code, they dont come up, which lets me know theyre not coming through. any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Hey original poster, long story short, i edited my code(based on yours) and added this to the top of it " if (function_exists('register_sidebar')) " and it worked. Edit your reply so i can mark it. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I assumed register_sidebar was already defined.

Answer (score 2):

Menus:

- [wp_nav_menu()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)
- [register_nav_menu()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu)

Widget Areas: [codex - Widgetizing Themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes)

Breadcrumbs: see this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/kCcKHyQi)

Comment: +1 for the pastebin. I'm officially swiping for later use :)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer all of your questions, but when I was learning the widgets it was hard for me to find a good reliable sample to learn from. So here's the one I used as reference to wrap my head around the `enigma` so to speak ;)

```
//CONSTRUCT Class
class my_custom_widget extends WP_Widget {
function my_custom_widget() {
    $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'text_plus_widget', 'description' => 'Title Bar, Text Area, and Link URL' );
    //WIDGET Name
    $this->WP_Widget('hs_text_plus', 'Text Plus Widget', $widget_ops);
}
//WIDGET Args
function widget($args, $instance) {
    extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);
    echo $before_widget;
    //WIDGET Database Checks
    $title = empty($instance['title']) ? ' ' : apply_filters('widget_hs_text_plus_title', $instance['title']);
    $text_area = empty($instance['text_area']) ? ' ' : apply_filters('widget_hs_text_plus_text_area', $instance['text_area']);
    $link_url = empty($instance['link_url']) ? ' ' : apply_filters('widget_hs_text_plus_link_url', $instance['link_url']);

    ?>
    <li>
        <?php if ( !empty( $title ) && (strlen($title) > 1 )) { echo $before_title . $title . $after_title; }; ?>
        <?php if ( !empty( $text_area ) && (strlen($text_area) > 1 )) { echo '<p>' . $text_area . '</p>'; }; ?>
        <?php if ( !empty( $link_url ) && (strlen($link_url) > 1 )) { echo '<a href="' . $link_url . '">Click Here to Learn More</a>'; }; ?>
        <div class="clr" style="display: block; height: 20px;"></div>
    </li>
    <?php
    echo $after_widget;
}
//WIDGET Save
function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
    $instance = $old_instance;
    $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
    $instance['text_area'] = strip_tags($new_instance['text_area']);
    $instance['link_url'] = strip_tags($new_instance['link_url']);
    return $instance;
}
//WIDGET Admin Form
function form($instance) {
    //set your params, $instance and then any additional variables needed below
    $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array( 'title' => '', 'text_area' => '', 'link_url' => '' ) );
    $title = strip_tags($instance['title']);
    $text_area = strip_tags($instance['text_area']);
    $link_url = strip_tags($instance['link_url']);
?>
        <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>">Widget Title: <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr__($title); ?>" /></label></p>
        <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('text_area'); ?>">Widget Text: <textarea class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('text_area'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('text_area'); ?>" ><?php echo esc_attr__($text_area); ?></textarea></label></p>
        <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('link_url'); ?>">Link URL: <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('link_url'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('link_url'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr__($link_url); ?>" /></label></p>
<?php
    }
}

 //CREATE Widget
 add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("my_custom_widget");') );
```

This isn't PHP5.3 syntax, however it's easily portable to that if you require it. Cheers!