# I can't get my custom widget area to show on my Wordpress site

Tags: php, widgets, register-sidebar

I can't get my sidebar to appear on my site. 
I add a widget section since there wasn't any:
**function.php**

```
<?php
if (function_exists('register_sidebar'))
    // Area 1
  register_sidebar( array (
  'name' => 'Primary Widget Area',
  'id' => 'primary_widget_area',
  'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget-container %2$s">',
  'after_widget' => "</li>",
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
  ) );

    // Area 2
  register_sidebar( array (
  'name' => 'Secondary Widget Area',
  'id' => 'secondary_widget_area',
  'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget-container %2$s">',
  'after_widget' => "</li>",
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
  ) );

    // Footer
  register_sidebar( array (
  'name' => 'Footer',
  'id' => 'footer_widget_area',
  'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget-container %2$s">',
  'after_widget' => "</li>",
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
  ) );
?>
```

**sidebar.php**

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-3' );  ?>
```

I'm following this tutorial: [WordPress Widgets Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QxeQBPgftRE&index=14&list=PLpcSpRrAaOaqMA4RdhSnnNcaqOVpX7qi5&nohtml5=False)
And I've tried many online examples and here are two: [wordpress custom modules/widget areas on the page? can i make my own?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49425/wordpress-custom-modules-widget-areas-on-the-page-can-i-make-my-own) and [Widgetizing Themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your have created three sidebars and that are `primary_widget_area`, `secondary_widget_area`, `footer_widget_area`

But in the sidebar, you call a different sidebar name `sidebar-3`; that's why your sidebars are not displaying.

Try the following code in sidebar.php:

```
// To display primary_widget_area sidebar
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'primary_widget_area' ) ) : ?>
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'primary_widget_area' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

// To display secondary_widget_areasidebar
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'secondary_widget_area' ) ) : ?>
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'secondary_widget_area' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

// To display footer_widget_areasidebar
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'footer_widget_area' ) ) : ?>
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'footer_widget_area' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: How do I mark this as resolved?

Comment: I am not sure as I am new here. I search around the web and I found the following:

Comment: Click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem. This marks the answer as "accepted", and by extension the question as "has an accepted answer".

Comment: @hasibrsohel -  why all the if statements?

Comment: @Michael - Sorry, I could not understand your query.